vue/compiler-sfc: .d.ts file generated does not include content from script setup
When I try to generate .d.ts files based on .vue and .ts file, the .d.ts generated file can not get the props from the Ts file imported.
Is it related to the new syntax with withDefaults(defineProps<>).... ?
Do you have any ideas ?
//vue file
<template>
    <div
        :ref="setup._el"
        class="orion-alert"
        :class="[
            `orion-alert--${color}`,
            { 'orion-alert--center': center },
        ]">
        <h5
            v-if="title"
            class="orion-alert__title">
            {{ title }}
        </h5>

        <span
            v-if="close"
            class="orion-alert__close"
            @click="emits('close')"
            @touchend.prevent.stop="emits('close')"/>

        <div class="orion-alert__contrast">
            <slot/>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import './OrionAlert.less';
import OrionAlertSetupService from './OrionAlertSetupService';
import type { OrionAlertProps, OrionAlertEmits } from './OrionAlertSetupService';
const emits = defineEmits<OrionAlertEmits>() as OrionAlertEmits;
const props = withDefaults(defineProps<OrionAlertProps>(), OrionAlertSetupService.defaultProps);
const setup = new OrionAlertSetupService(props, emits);

defineExpose(setup.publicInstance);
</script>

The generated file is empty:
declare const _default: import("vue").DefineComponent<
any, (_ctx: any, _cache: any) => import("vue").VNode<import("vue").RendererNode, import("vue").RendererElement, {
    [key: string]: any;
}>, {}, {}, {}, import("vue").ComponentOptionsMixin, import("vue").ComponentOptionsMixin, "close"[], "close", import("vue").PublicProps, any, any, {}, {}, {}, string, import("vue").ComponentProvideOptions, true, {}, any>;
export default _default;


the compiler options:
compilerOptions: {
 allowJs: true,
 strict: true,
 declaration: true,
 emitDeclarationOnly: true,
 outDir: this.typesPath,
 include: ["src/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.vue"],
 paths: {
  "@/*": ["src/*"]
 },
 "types": ["vite/client", "vue"]
},

